# Get the contents of an uploaded file without storing it

Tags: php, upload

Say the user uploads a text file using PHP on my website. I want to get just the contents of this text file, and then process them, without having to store the file/do move_uploded_file() anywhere on the disk, so I won't have to deal with deleting it when I'm done with it, etc.

Is there a way to get the file's contents using the tmp_name or any other info?

Comment: Have you tried file_get_contents on the tmp_name? (out of curiosity)

Comment: @MyStream I did now, and it worked. Post answer and I'll accept :)

Comment: Excellent :) posted answer below. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can retrieve information related to uploaded file using $_FILES Super global array.

$_FILES['input-field-name']['tmp_name'] will store the name of temporary copy of uploaded file on the server

So you can retrieve the contents of uploaded file using file_get_contents() function  through passing value of $_FILES['input-field-name']['tmp_name'] as arguement .

The temporary copy is removed after script execution is terminated.

Please refer the example code snippet mentioned below.

```
<?php if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST')
      {
         if(isset($_FILES['input-field-name']))
         {

         $file_content=file_get_contents($_FILES['input-field-name']['tmp_name']);
         }
      }
  ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

In this instance:

`file_get_contents()` on the `tmp_name` part of `$_POST['filename']['tmp_name']` might suffice.

Assuming your file's input name attribute has a value of 'filename'.